# show all orders made by one user

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
$email = $_GET['email'];
$order_id = $_GET['order_id'];
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients_buy WHERE email='$email'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th><center>order_id</center></th>
<th><center>item1</th>
<th><center>item2</th>
<th><center>item3</th>
<th><center>item4</th>
<th><center>item5</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
$row[] = $row;
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['user_id'] . "</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['item1'] . "</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['item2'] . "</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['item3'] . "</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['item4'] . "</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['item5'] . "</center></td>";
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

I want to show in php page all orders made from one user.

Comment: Very first thing switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO` because `mysql` is dead now and stop using direct variables in you SQL this opens up a security risk called SQLinjection so please read on using prepared statements as well. Now what is you problem you don't seems to mention you problem. Are you getting any errors or what ?

Comment: it doesn't shows nothing this is the problem. I'm a begineer i don't understand very much PDO.Maybe mysqli

Comment: you can help me with the correct format please ?

Comment: Why did you use ->  **$row[] = $row;**....

Comment: If I show you it in `PDO` you won't understand as you said you don't know `PDO` but `mysqli` is the same thing but I've lost touch with it. Well you can use browser console to see if there's any errors.

Answer (score 0):

As Sand commented, please use mysqli or PDO. How come you don't have curly braces on the while loop? That seems to be a course for mistake though have not tested your code.
i would write it as

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['user_id'] . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['item1'] . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['item2'] . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['item3'] . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['item4'] . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['item5'] . "</center></td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Nice spot I missed it.